# mail() in PHP on localhost (fedora 22) not sending emails

Tags: php, linux, email, lamp, libstdc++

I have problem with sending emails in PHP,I have lampp installed.

On my linux I have postfix, when I send from my terminal all works fine.
For example: 
this works and sends email:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -f -t myaddress@gmail.com < message_body.txt
```

In my php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/send-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path ="/usr/sbin/sendmail -f -t "
```

This is my mail script...

```
$send = mail("me@gmail.com", "My subject", $msg);

    if($send)
    {
        echo "ok";
    }
    else{
        echo "Failed to send";


    }
```

This is what my error log from /opt/lamp/logs says when I try to send

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib64/libicuuc.so.54)
/usr/sbin/sendmail: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib64/libicuuc.so.54)
/usr/sbin/sendmail: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib64/libicuuc.so.54)
/usr/sbin/sendmail: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib64/libicuuc.so.54)
/usr/sbin/sendmail: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib64/libicuuc.so.54)
/usr/sbin/sendmail: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib64/libicuuc.so.54)
```

Thank you for advise

Comment: You don't even care explaining if your script prints `ok` or `failed to send`. But if your sendmail program is not working properly, there isn't much that PHP can do.

Comment: I am sorry, it prints Failed to send. 
 it is not because of PHP I uderstand, probably it is something with /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6 and its version.... BUT DUNNO WHAT ON EARTH :)

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

From your operative system copy the libstdc++.so.6 inside the lampp library folder (/opt/lampp/lib/). For instance in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS:

```
 cp /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```